# In a reaction if the equilibrium constant K was infinity, could you produce an infinite number of products at equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

It's impossible to produce an infinite amount products if the k constant was infinity?

no right?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that you'd only have an infinite equilibrium constant if the denominator was exactly zero (i.e., not just very small, but zero), the amount of product you produce will be limited by the amount of starting material. At most, you could only produce 100% molar yield.

Comment: but at equilibrium, wouldnt the reaction constantly go forward and backwards and never end?

Comment: As stated in the answer, an infinite K would mean that the forward reaction will go to completion and the backwards reaction will never occur.

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible, law of conservation of mass and energy immediately comes to mind. All an infinite K value means is that the forward reaction will go to completion.